# Making a simple to use dynamic MySQL class that can read from and write to a database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a script that runs any query from through PHP the same way you would run it through the MySQL console just by calling `MySQL::query([the query]);`.

I have created a good portion of the PHP script already but I think I'm stuck. So far it can pull information just fine but it does not like it when I try to make any changes to the database itself. I would like it to also write to MySQL as well, but I can't figure out how to do it dynamically.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<?php

    include '..\..\shared\Error_Code.php';

    class MySQL {
        private static $host;
        private static $username;
        private static $password;
        private static $database;
        private static $logged_in = false;

        public static function login($host, $username, $password, $database) {
            self::$host = $host;
            self::$username = $username;
            self::$password = $password;
            self::$database = $database;
            if (self::confirm_login()) {
                self::$logged_in = true;
            } else {
                self::$logged_in = false;
                Error_Code::print(107.0); //There was an issue with the login.
            }
        }
        public static function change_database($database) {
            if (self::$logged_in) {
                $old_database = self::$database;
                self::$database = $database;
                if (!self::confirm_login()) {
                    self::$database = $database;
                    Error_Code::print(107.1); //The database you entered dose not exist.
                }
            } else {
                Error_Code::print(107.2); //You have not logged in yet.
            }
        }
        private static function confirm_login($host = -1, $username = -1, $password = -1, $database = -1) {
            $host = (($host != -1) ? $host : self::$host);
            $username = (($username != -1) ? $username : self::$username);
            $password = (($password != -1) ? $password : self::$password);
            $database = (($database != -1) ? $database : self::$database);

            if (!(is_null(self::$host) || is_null(self::$username) || is_null(self::$password) || is_null(self::$database))) {
                $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);

                if ($connection) {
                    $response = mysqli_query($connection, "SHOW DATABASES");

                    $bg_db = array("information_schema", "mysql", "performance_schema", "phpmyadmin", "test");
                    if (!in_array(self::$database, $bg_db)) {
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)) {
                            if($row['Database'] == self::$database) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Error_Code::print(107.8); //Login information is wrong.
                    return false;
                } else {
                    Error_Code::print(107.9); //Login information is wrong.
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                Error_Code::print(107.7); //Login information is missing.
                return false;
            }
        }
        public static function logged_in() {
            return self::$logged_in;
        }
        public static function query($query, $host = -1, $username = -1, $password = -1, $database = -1) {
            $host = (($host != -1) ? $host : self::$host);
            $username = (($username != -1) ? $username : self::$username);
            $password = (($password != -1) ? $password : self::$password);
            $database = (($database != -1) ? $database : self::$database);
            $continue = self::confirm_login($host, $username, $password, $database);

            if ($continue) {
                return new Data($query, $host, $username, $password, $database);
            } else {
                return new Data($query, $host, $username, $password, $database);
                Error_Code::print(107.3); //You have not logged into a database.
            }
        }
    }

    class Data {
        private $query;
        private $host;
        private $username;
        private $password;
        private $database;

        public function __construct($query, $host, $username, $password, $database) {
            if ($query < 0) {
                return $this;
            } else {
                $this->query = $query;
                $this->host = $host;
                $this->username = $username;
                $this->password = $password;
                $this->database = $database;
                return $this->get();
            }
        }

        //get data from a database using an SQL query
        public function get() {
            //query database
            $connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
            if ($connection) {
                $response = mysqli_query($connection, $this->query);

                //get data from query
                if ($response) {
                    $rows = array();
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                        array_push($rows, $row);
                    }
                    return $rows;
                } else {
                    if (true) { 
                        //<----- I THINK THIS IS WHERE I WOULD HAVE TO ADD THE CODE FOR MAKING CHANGES TO THE DATABASE 
                        //$prepare = mysqli_prepare($connection, $this->query);
                        //mysqli_stmt_execute($prepare);
                    } else {
                        Error_Code::print(108.0); //Could not run query because there was no response
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Error_Code::print(108.1); //Could not run query because there was no connection
                return -1;
            }
        }

        //print the results of the query to a table
        public function print_table($table_id = -1) {
            $data = $this->get();
            if ($data < 0) {
                Error_Code::print(108.2); //Could not build table do to an issue with the query.
                return -1;
            } else {
                $th = "<tr>";
                foreach ($data[0] as $col => $value) {
                    $th = "$th<th>$col</th>";
                }
                $th = "$th</tr>";

                $td = "";
                foreach ($data as $row) {
                    $td = "$td<tr>";
                    foreach ($row as $col => $value) {
                        $td = "$td<td>$value</td>";
                    }
                    $td = "$td</tr>";
                }

                $table_id = ($table_id < 0) ? "" : " id='$table_id'";
                echo "<table class='database_data'$table_id>$th$td</table>";
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Any ideas on what I can change to get it to `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` and everything else.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you want to use this?

Comment: @bassxzero `$all_classes = MySQL::query("SELECT * FROM classes"); $all_classes->print_table(); MySQL::query("INSERT INTO classes VALUE (NULL, 'Art')"); $all_classes->print_table();`

Comment: Must be a current assignment at U of somewhere. This is the second one of these I have seen today! Or is it your second try at an answer

Comment: I think Single Responsibility Principle is your biggest problem. Generating output is not a responsibility of `Data`. If you remove `print_table` from the  `Data` class then you're basically just creating a wrapper for wrapper. Mysqli already has a query wrapper it's called a statement. Insert, update, and delete queries don't return data so you're going to run into problems there. Also you're not passing in parameters and most queries will need them. If you really want to do something like this then I think the Command pattern might be helpful.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's my second try at getting an answer. I shouldn't have posted it right before bed. That was just dumb of me. :)

Comment: What I am hope for is a way were I can post a query to the database, have it do whatever the query wants it to do then if there is a response (SELECT ...), then return the response, if there is no response (INSERT ...) then return `true`; it it did connect but there was an issue with the query (SELCT ...) then it would return an error message saying so; and if it was unable connect for it to return a different error message indicating as much.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: 
https://github.com/indieteq/indieteq-php-my-sql-pdo-database-class

It might be a bit too much for your needs, but is, in my opinion, a great example of how to build a database class